# Preparing an integrated band depth image

Tags: remote-sensing, digital-image-processing

How do I prepare an integrated band depth image?

If I have to prepare an 1 micrometer integrated band depth image (sum of 0.79 and 1.3 band depth micrometer bands),  do I just average all bands from 0.79 and 1.3 micrometers?

Comment: Could you please supply more details on the problem?

Comment: @Aaron . I am currently working with M3 hyper-spectral data to delineate mineral abundances. I need to know how to prepare a band depth image for a particular band and an integrated band depth image for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Some quality Research has been done on IBD by Varatharajan et al and Cheek et al. I suggest you read their Research papers.Cheek et al. have given IBD @ 1000nm as :

[image]